# Replacing a string using replaceAll or Pattern Matcher

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to replace a string having say for example "8:00 AM - 5:00 PM" with "8:00 AM ET - 5:00 PM ET"

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work...

```
time.replaceAll("AM", "AM ET");
time.replaceAll("PM", "PM ET");
convertedTime = time;
System.out.println(convertedTime); // didnt get replaced
```

I tried below way and its working but not getting replaced properly,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(AM)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(time);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "AM ET");
    } 
m.appendTail(sb); 
p = Pattern.compile("(PM)");
m = p.matcher(time);
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "PM ET");
    } 
m.appendTail(sb); 

System.out.println("sb: " + sb); // coming as sb: 8:00 AM ET - 5:00 PM8:00 AM - 5:00 PM ET
```

Please let me know why the first approach did not work, and if it possible to correct in second approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call the `replaceAll()` method, it returns a new `String` with the modified value - it doesn't change the original `String`.

Your code should therefore be...

```
String convertedTime = time.replaceAll("AM", "AM ET");
convertedTime = convertedTime.replaceAll("PM", "PM ET");
System.out.println(convertedTime);
```

or even this...

```
String convertedTime = time.replaceAll("AM", "AM ET").replaceAll("PM", "PM ET");
System.out.println(convertedTime);
```

Due to the simplicity of the above code, I wouldn't really suggest that you use your Pattern-based code - its just too overly-complicated to achieve the same result. However, seeing as though you asked, you would probably just need to change your `m = p.matcher(time);` line to `m = p.matcher(sb.toString());`, and clear your `StringBuffer`, so that you're feeding the result of the first modification into the second `p.matcher()` method, and to remove the `duplicate` in the output. Something like this...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(AM)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(time);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "AM ET");
    } 
m.appendTail(sb); 
p = Pattern.compile("(PM)");
m = p.matcher(sb.toString()); // CHANGED
sb = new StringBuffer(); // ADDED
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "PM ET");
    } 
m.appendTail(sb); 

System.out.println("sb: " + sb);
```

But, as I said, it'd be much better and simpler to just use `replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-assigning the returned Strings from the methods. e.g. `time = time.replaceAll("AM", "AM ET");`